# Pine Script- Background Color of First Bar

Tags: pine-script

In Trading View Pine Script, 
How to make Background Color of Day's First 30 Min Bar Color into Balck

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("")
bgcolor(change(dayofweek) ? color.black : na)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25005965)

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study(title="30 minute bg ranges color", overlay=true)

// Create the inputs
Session_time = input(title="Enter your country's starting time session",type=input.session,defval="0800-0830")


transparency = input(title="Transparency", type=input.integer,defval=50, minval=0, maxval=100)

// The BarInSession function returns true when
// the current bar is inside the session parameter
BarInSession(sess) => time(period, sess) != 0

// Set the colour variables for the ranges
tm_Colour =color.black // Cornflower blue

// Determine the chart's background colour
chartColour = BarInSession(Session_time ) ? tm_Colour : na

// Set the background colour
bgcolor(color=chartColour, transp=transparency)
```

the above code will work on all time frames , you need to input the session time in the code or you can input the time in the user interface input according to your country's starting 30min time.